# Whenever i click on any anchor element, the window jumps to top in Mobile.

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, dropdown, preventdefault

I am making responsive dropdown menu. It is working nicely in Laptop, but when i click on any link in this dropdown using my android mobile, the window jumps to the top. I tried to use preventDefault in the JQuery, but I think the Dropdown is powered by CSS Hover action, thats why PreventDefault method is not working. Any Idea what should i add in my JQuery to prevent this, because its very annoying.
Here is the link.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naeemrind/4yxa9koj/)

I am using this Script to toggle the text.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".show-menu").click(function(){
            if ($(this).text() == "Show Menu")
               {
                   $(this).text("Close");    } else 
                   {
                       $(this).text("Show Menu");
                   };
            });


      });
```

Comment: you may try: $('#menu a').on('click', function(e) {e.preventDefault(); })

Comment: Its working. I was using the preventDefault method, but my method was not right. :)

Comment: Is there any way to make the menu open and close smoothly?

Comment: Don't use `anchor` tags unless you want them to be anchored to somewhere - another page, another place on the current page. Why not use a `span` or a `button` element? That way, you don't have to use `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` in your click handler.

Comment: I have to use anchor tags in this page. because i will anchor them to other pages. But i will keep your advice in my mind for future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".show-menu").click(function(e){
        if ($(this).text() == "Show Menu")
           {
               $(this).text("Close");    } else 
               {
                   $(this).text("Show Menu");
               };
        });
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
  });
```

Alternatively you can use the below code and remove your hover functions in the css file.

```
$("#menu li").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("ul.hidden").fadeIn("fast");
}, function(){
    $(this).find("ul.hidden").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Comment: I already tried this method. its not working. But the method provided by gaetanoM in the first comment is working.

Comment: Is there any way to make the menu open and close smoothly?

Comment: So far it looks quite smooth but have you tried the hover option? 

try this the above added code

Comment: I tried your method. I just added the stop() method as well. Now its working smoothly, checked it on my phone as well. :) Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return false;` in addition to `.preventDefault()` at the end of `click(){ }` to prevent the default action.